# get keyboard height before keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, keyboard

Is there a way to get keyboard height before keyboard even appears?

I want to create a login screen similar to what instagram has, where textfields are placed in such a spot that keyboard comes up right under them (as you can see on the screenshots).

[image: textfield not selected] 
[image: textfield selected]

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I bet I know how Instagram does it.

When you launch Instagram for the first time, it displays the Username and Password screen WITH the keyboard (your second screenshot).  Since it's displaying the keyboard as soon as it launches, I'm betting that it repositions the login screen, then saves the keyboard height in an `NSUserDefault`.  Possibly you could test this by installing a different keyboard, with a different height.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram must be using a custom keyboard, check here how to implement your own (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html). It's height is calculated after the textfield view.

> To adjust a custom keyboard’s height, change its primary view's height constraint. The following code lines show how you might define and add such a constraint:

```
CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500;
NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                    toItem: nil 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
                                multiplier: 0.0 
                                  constant: _expandedHeight];
[self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

Comment: Well, I doubt it since the keyboard provided in the instagram app doesnt have any language switch option, which is a must with custom keyboards if you want to get your app through approval process.

Comment: @andrejbroncek In case if multilingual keyboard is not a feasible solution Apple proposes to "create one keyboard per language, each as a separate target that you add to a common containing app."

Comment: Hmm, that could be then :) Thank you for your insight.